# Delete all rows of Table in Hibernate 4.2.21

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, oracle11g, oracle12c

I'm working with oracle 12c, and Hibernate 4.2.21, I want to delete two tables in telationship OnetoMany.

My method is with delete From "Table":

```
public void deleteAllRecords() {
        Session session = HibernateSessionFactory.getSessionFactory()
                .openSession();

        try {
            session.beginTransaction();

//          String hql = String.format("TRUNCATE table MapField");
//          Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
//          query.executeUpdate();

            Query q1 = session.createQuery ("DELETE FROM MapField");
            int deleted = q1.executeUpdate ();

            Query q2 = session.createQuery ("DELETE FROM MapRecord");
            int deleted = q2.executeUpdate ();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error :" + e);
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
```

When I execute this, I dond't receive none Error , only this:

```
INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) Hibernate: delete from MapField
```

But when I go to check the Tables in the Db, the rows still are here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to commit your transaction after `q2.executeUpdate();`

```
session.getTransaction().commit();
```